# Missing directories in NppFTP

Tags: notepad++

I use NppFTP plugin on NotePad++ to connect with my web server. Other than the www folder, I have two other sub-domains say aaa and bbb. Connection with www is fine. But I cannot access the sub-domains. There is no navigation to the sub-domain folders. I tried to set the host to aaa.example.com but still it shows only the www folder. Any idea? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When NppFTP initially connects, it only shows the default directory. If you right click on it, and request for Refresh, it will show the others.

[image]

Comment: I tested on it. if user account is for a single sub-domain, then it is restricted to that. On the other hand, if access rights to other folders, then Refresh will bring them up as should be.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably only two reasons for this. Either the folders were deleted or you do not have permission to access the folders. The former would most likely be be the case.

Try using another FTP application just to confirm it's not a bug in Notepadd++, I would recommend Leechftp. Otherwise you can just use Telnet or putty to check whether the folders still exists on the server.

Comment: Indeed confirmed using Filezilla that the folders are there and permission allowed.